# What are some good C++ resources for effectively using Apache XML Security?

Tags: c++, xml, security, apache, resources

I'm looking for some resources that allow me to understand how to use this library, particularly for signing XML. Most of what I found out there is Java related, and I would prefer to get documentation/FAQs/tutorials on the C++ library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. The best information I could find was on the Apache website itself ( http://santuario.apache.org/c/programming.html ), the API docs and by looking at the code of the examples and tools (like templatesign) they provide.

This information combined with some experimenting was enough for me to sign and verify XML documents. Basically I just used templatesign and checksig as starting point.

The most problems I had was with C14N, so if there is something not working try dumping the raw data streams which Apache is using internally and check if it really signs/verifies what you expect.